# Google Maps V3 javascript -- customizing the infowindow when clicking pins

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey guys -- I was looking to create an entire custom info window for pin description.
I am not looking to insert a custom div within the popup window, but actually redesign the window itself.

I saw an article on here http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/boundsbox/tiptool_trains.htm
This is **not** what I'm looking for, the rounded bubble needs to go

I was hoping to find an article or some tips on how to go about this?
Right now I'm thinking of creating a custom overlay by extendin  some functionality of some extendable classes/functions of the API.
Where would a good place to start be? Has anyone done this here?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a  [custom infowindow example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) in [demo gallery](http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html?searchquery=infowindow) section of the google map api documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a click listener (using [`google.maps.event.addListener`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#event)) to your marker and then build your own popup when the marker is clicked:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    /* build and show your popup in any way you want. */
});
```

If you're thinking about the little tooltip-ish popup from your example, then you'd want to bind a listener to the [`mouseover`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#UIEvents) to popup your tip and [`mouseout`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#UIEvents) to get rid of it.

Comment: Right -- i get the binding, but the construction of a custom overlay so it stays within the actual canvas and tiles?

Comment: @Jobsz: AFAIK, you have to do all the sizing and positioning yourself. You already where the map is and how big it is and you can get the current position of the marker, that should be all you need.